# Why doesn’t “NET USE” work as expected?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

From the command line I run:

```
NET USE P: \\192.168.1.121\Oz_bk /persistent:yes /u:domain\admin password /YES
```

And get this message:

> The network connection could not be found.

Then I ping the same network drive and get the expected response:

```
C:\Users\tulih>ping 192.168.1.121

Pinging 192.168.1.121 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.121: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.121: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.121: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.121: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Any ideas why I can't map the shares on this drive?

Comment: I use /user: instead of /u:   ... Something like a syntax error.

Comment: What OS is 192.168.1.121 running

Answer (score 2):

For starters you have 2 syntax errors in that command.
The /U parameter must be /USER and the /YES at the end shouldn't be there at all.

After you have fixed that, if you still get the error, make sure you've got the name of the share correct. Windows doesn't care, but some other operating systems can be case-sensitive regarding the name of the share.

If it still fails, some other problems may be the culprit. The most common ones are:
The share may not actually be at 192.168.1.121 but on an other ip-address.
The computer publishing the share may have a local firewall that is blocking SMB access.